# WebDriver - InternetExplorerDriver standalone server for 32-bit IE, What is the purpose, how can I use this

Tags: webdriver

In WebDirver downloads page, I have seen InternetExplorerDriver standalone server. What is the actual purpose of this. How can I use it?
Where can I find the document?

Answer (score 1):

This is a standalone server for use with the IE driver, much like the standalone server used with the Chrome driver. It is not necessary yet, but will be required in future versions of the Selenium library. A pretty thorough discussion of what the standalone server is was posted to the [WebDriver user-facing mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/webdriver/lFNs89v2cBw/DilIhQafvOwJ).

Answer (score 0):

The standalone IEdriver used to run script in InternetExplorer browser, to run the script you have to download the internetExplorerDriver standalone server,
If you using Eclipse then you have to set path of the driver using then call IEdriver it open IE browser

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "path of driver");
 WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

or

```
    DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); 
       ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
         WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
```