# How would I speed up obtaining elements on a table using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am testing an application with a lot of tables. each cell in the table contains a variety of things that i may need, such as the id to input text, id for a drop down, checkboxes, and so forth.
I am using a solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198947/how-to-get-text-from-each-cell-of-an-html-table), but I have so many elements it bogs this down and on a table that has 5 rows and 21 columns it takes at least 120 seconds to obtain all of the data I need.

here is some code I am using

```
String[] additInfo = {"name", "id", "value"};

String firstClassName = "tableClassName";
String cssSelector = "tbody tr";

String additInfoName = additInfo[0];

int rowNum, colNum;
rowNum = 0;
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.className(firstClassName));
List<WebElement> row = table.findElements(By.cssSelector(cssSelector));
print.ln("# of rows: " + row.size());

for (WebElement rowElement : row) {

 System.out.println("get row elms");
  List<WebElement> column = rowElement.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
  System.out.println("number of col: " + column.size());

  colNum = 0;
  for (WebElement colElement : column) {
    String tableText = colElement.getText();
    System.out.println("row # " + rowNum + ", col # " + colNum + " text: " + tableText);

    WebElement nestedElm;

    System.out.println("Get additional Info for " + additInfoName);
    String infoUnderTag = "class";
    nestedElm = colElement.findElement(By.tagName(infoUnderTag));

    for (int i = 1; i < additInfo.length; i++) {
      String attribute = nestedElm.getAttribute(additInfo[i]);
      System.out.println("\t" + additInfo[i] + ": " + attribute);
      
    }
    colNum++;

  } //end Elements

  rowNum++;
} //end rows
```

Is there any way of speeding this up? I took out some unnecessary findElements commands which doubled the speed, but it is still very slow on those larger tables.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which browser do you use? If you can, use Chrome, it is faster than Firefox or IE.

Comment: I'm using IE and have to stick with it unfortunately .

Comment: I found a solution for now. I was using IE9 64 bit version. From what I found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/selenium-users/lVjGr7ZtrtQ/V3OAX3nEYAMJ) the 64 bit version of IE does not have the faster JavaScript engine, only the 32 bit version. I changed my webdriver to open that [version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595420/webdriver-internetexplorerdriver-standalone-server-for-32-bit-ie-what-is-the) instead, and it is running much faster then before. Not nearly as quick as firefox though...

Comment: Have you tried profiling your Selenium session using JProfiler or some ad-hoc println(timestamp)? You could see right away which part takes up the most time. It shouldn't take so much time to go through such a small table. Maybe the part where you're iterating through an element's attributes? Is this really necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for now. I was using IE9 64 bit version. From what I found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/selenium-users/lVjGr7ZtrtQ/V3OAX3nEYAMJ) the 64 bit version of IE does not have the faster JavaScript engine, only the 32 bit version. I changed my WebDriver to open that IEDriverServer.exe [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595420/webdriver-internetexplorerdriver-standalone-server-for-32-bit-ie-what-is-the) instead, and it is running 3 or 4 times faster then before. Not nearly as quick as Firefox however.